# Como salvar a saída (stdout) de um outro programa em um arquivo utilizando Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Exemplo, eu dou o comando no terminal:

```
import os

os.system('ipconfig')
```

Isso me retorna o ipconfig igual ao comando no CMD, porém eu preciso pegar o resultado que mostrou no terminal e salvar em um arquivo txt que no meu caso é o `resultado.txt`, porém não consigo.

Segue código completo:

```
import os

def save(filename, info):
    file = open('{}'.format(filename), 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
    file.write(info + '\n')
    file.close()

save('resultado.txt', os.system('ipconfig'))
```

Até procurei perguntas parecidas, mas não consegui localizar algo que seja conclusivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em outra reposta você encontrará o uso do subprocess, **bem mais elegante** que a resposta que eu apresento aqui. Porém, esta é bem mais simples.

```
import os

def save(filename, comando):
    comando_completo = f"{comando} > {filename}"
    os.system(comando_completo)

save('resultado.txt', 'ipconfig')
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Sensacional, funcionou perfeitamente, Obrigado, Paulo!

Comment: Só de duvida esse f" serve pra que ?

Comment: f-string : exemplo: `print(f"O vavor é {sua_variavel}")` é o equivalente a `print("O valor é %s" % str(sua_variavel))`. Acho que o f-string passou a existir a partir da 3.7 - Veja mais [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Não conhecia, agora já aprendi mais uma rsrs Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a documentação de `os.system`:

> No Unix, o valor de retorno é o status de saída do processo codificado no formato especificado para `wait()`. Observe que POSIX não especifica o significado do valor de retorno da função C `system()`, então o valor de retorno da função Python é dependente do sistema.
>
> No Windows, o valor de retorno é aquele retornado pelo shell do sistema após a execução de *command*. O shell é fornecido pela variável de ambiente Windows `COMSPEC`: normalmente é `cmd.exe`, que retorna o status de saída da execução do comando; em sistemas que usam um shell não nativo, consulte a documentação do shell.

Então utilizar `os.system` para obter o *output* *stdout* de um programa não é uma boa ideia.

Uma opção é utilizar a função [`run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), do módulo `subprocess`. Mais ou menos assim:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE


def save(filename, info):
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(info)


result = run('ifconfig', stdout=PIPE)
save('resultado.txt', result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Note que passamos o argumento `stdout` como `subprocess.PIPE` para que ele possa ser capturado. Além disso, `result.stdout` é um *bytes object*, de modo que utilizamos o método `decode` para convertê-lo para uma string UTF-8.

Como `run` é relativamente recente no Python (>= versão 3.5), você pode utilizar a função [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) do mesmo módulo se precisar de um suporte mais antigo.